# Open .exe file through .bat file in Flask

Tags: python, html, windows, batch-file, flask

I am trying to open an .exe file (e.g. Paint) with a html button using Flask, so I wrote a small .bat file that runs it properly when I run it through Python, but does not seem to work when I open it through Flask.

The Python is:

```
@app.route('/assemblies', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def assemblies():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['submit'] == 'runFile':
            #os.startfile("/static/run.bat")
            text = "... running ..."
            filepath="/static/run.bat"
            p = subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
            stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
            return render_template('assemblies.html', text=text)
        else request.form['submit'] == 'process':
            [do other stuff]
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('assemblies.html')
```

(Part of) the html file is:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="/assemblies" method="post"> ASSEMBLY <br> 
        <select name="Layer">
            <option value="1">1</option>        
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select><br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="process"> Process </button>
        <button  type="submit" name="submit" value="runFile"> Run </button> 
    </form>
</div>
```

And the bat is:

```
start /d "static\" myFile.exe
```

The bat file works outside Flask, but I have tried with the exe and bat both in the 'static' folder and on C:/ and seems to be completely unresponsive (no console feedback), so I assume I might be missing something important?

Comment: if you want console output try and use `subprocess.call` `Popen` doesn't block and is asynchronous, you can also look at the `stderr` variable and see if there's anything that might lead you to the problem, and i don't see why you need a `.bat` file (you could just call your exe from python direclty)

Comment: Cheers @danidee, I am trying to use `Popen`, but no success... I'll have a look to the `stderr` docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution after changing:

```
filepath="/static/run.bat"
p = subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
stdout,  = p.communicate()
```

for:

```
subprocess.call(["static/myFile.exe"])
```

and now it works. I am bypassing the bat file, but not sure what was the problem with the original script, so any insights are still welcome.